Trasparenza nell'uso del sistema
Traggo spunto da un commento di @linux che è stato cancellato per fare presente che questo sito ormai non ha più nulla a che fare con il suo senso iniziale e che si è ridotto a un sistema di antagonismi personali in cui non contano più le risposte, bensì downvotes e upvotes usati in modo anonimo in base a conflitti preesistenti con altri utenti. Se una domanda semplice riceve tot upvotes senza che venga provvista una semplice risposta e quando l'unica semplice risposta viene downvotata "en masse" abbiamo chiaramente a che fare con un sistema di incuiccio che ho già segnalato al management generale (che mi ha risposto che se ne occuperà). Quindi mi augurerei un attimino più di distacco e un atteggiamento più professionale da parte dei moderatori oltre che a un coraggio civico che pare essere scomparso.
Aggiorno questo post per dimostrare oggettivamente ciò a cui mi riferivo. Riguardo alla seguente domanda: Che programmi hai per + article/no article?
ho postato una risposta che ha ricevuto 2 downvotes. Quella di @charo che segue in sostanza il mio modo di argomentare 3 upvotes. Provare per credere! Caro @egreg perché non scrivi a @charo, come l'hai fatto con me, che la risposta è di bassa qualità visto che la domanda chiedeva il perché del fenomeno “look at your examples: some words want the articles, some not”. The question is why they do"?

Nico, potresti essere un po' più chiaro? Non riesco veramente a capire cosa vuoi dire con questo post: un riferimento a quale commento di linuxfan ti riferisci sarebbe anche utile (anche solo il post su cui è stato lasciato).

I deleted many comments by you and linuxfan in the past few days. For some reason you two do not seem to be able to stay on topic in the comments. It is of course possible that I made a mistake on one of them, given the amount I had to moderate, so being more specific would actually be helpful. PS I am writing in English to make review easier by an external party, were it to be necessary.

Mass downvotes? I see two answers of yours that have received three downvotes, which doesn't qualify for “mass”. One of them has been deleted, the other one is still online, as far as I can see. In my opinion it is very low quality (but I didn't downvote it).

@egreg Why is it very low quality?

@Nico It's just: “look at your examples: some words want the articles, some not”. The question is why they do.

@Nico You should be more careful when judging other people's expertises. There surely are reasons for the contrast in “Quali sono i tuoi programmi per sabato/l'estate?” (zero article versus article). Ever heard “Quali sono i tuoi programmi per settimana prossima?” (horrible, but frequent)?

@egreg The question is not "why they do", but " Is there any rule when to use an article?". So please read the questions carefully! Thanks!

@egreg Have I referred to downvotes regarding me in the OP? No! Once again, please stick to the question!

@DenisNardin Why should a review be necessary? Is Meta a place for reviews by external parties? Could you provide a link that confirms your assertion?

Che cos'è un “incuiccio”?

Oh, I see, thanks. So did you mean an “inciucio”?

I see the update now. Don't you really perceive any difference among your and Charo's answers?

Please reread my update with regard to egreg' s critique. Does @charo explain why? I see no difference apart from the fact that she has quoted some references.

@Nico if you cannot see any substantial difference in presentation and rigor between your answer and Charo's, I'm not sure I can help you here. Instead of railing against the world I suggest you try to see the differences that sparked such reactions to the two answers. This is not a conspiracy against you: this is just the result of the other users of the website deciding that one answer is much better than the other one, like SE is supposed to work.

@DenisNardin Please motivate your comment in an objective way. "Railing"  is not objective.

@DenisNardin I am still awaiting an objective answer that motivates the "substantial difference". Screenshot done.

@Nico That was just a piece of advice to you. Downvotes here are as free as the upvotes, I don't control them in any way. I was simply suggesting that trying to examine successful answers might be more productive that complaining that no one like yours. That said, look at how every sentence is motivated, and also at the formatting (your answers tend to always be an unreadable block of text)

@DenisNardin What kind of experise do you have in linguistics? Once again, you seem not to understand my question, which I repeat: "Please motivate your comment in an objective way. "Railing" is not objective". The use of "railing" by a moderator is definitely a reason for complaining! Screenshot 2

@Nico My expertise in linguistics is beside the point: I am just trying to explain how you can write answers that (with the same essential content!) are better received by the community. But I see that I am wasting my time, again, so I'll stop.

Moderators don't have a page listing all the deleted comments, whenever that was done from moderators or other users. I would not expect a moderator knows of which comment I am speaking just because the comment was deleted by that moderator. If you recall for which answer or question was posted, that would help a moderator, since moderators can still see the deleted comments posted for a question or an answer.

We moderators have analyzed the voting patterns and no evidence of targeted downvoting towards you has emerged. Really, it seems to me that you are getting upset by a small amount of downvotes to your answers.
I already told you extensively why I do not think your reactions to criticism is productive, so I won't repeat it further.
As usual, if you are unsatisfied with the moderators' behaviour on a SE website, you are encouraged to make use of the appropriate avenues for complaints.

I was not only alking about myself + a crucial point (borrowed from @linux) was that some users receive strange and sudden upvotes...

@Nico To be even more explicit: no suspicious voting patterns have emerged (and yes, we do keep an eye on it). It is your right to disagree with the vast majority of users on this website, but this does not mean that the other users should suddenly change their mind and align to your opinions, especially since you do not seem in the habit of providing any justifications for them.

I expressed my opinion without expecting anyone to align to it. This assertion of yours is simply unfounded.

Mi sembra che vengano portate accuse generiche, senza nemmeno un esempio. Tutti i moderatori hanno accesso anche ai commenti cancellati; se lo spunto viene da un commento cancellato, basta segnalare a quale domanda o risposta si riferiva.
Se si ritiene che ci siano schemi di voto “strani”, non è difficile fare un breve elenco, con i link per controllare.
Riporto uno screenshot della pagina con le “newest questions”, dove non riesco a vedere eccesso di upvotes a domande.

Fa forse eccezione la domanda sull'articolo davanti alle specificazioni temporali, che trovo interessante soprattutto perché viene da un utente la cui lingua è priva dell'articolo.

Pure io trovo la domanda sull'articolo interessante, ma come scrivevo ieri, la domanda non era "perché", bensì in quali casi. Ora, io ho iniziato a stilare una classificazione (che è l'unica maniera di rispondere alla domanda), ma poi come al solito son piovute le critiche, come accade regolarmente quando rispondo io...

@Nico La domanda comincia con Why, il cui significato mi sembra chiaro.

Molto spesso capita che chi formula lo faccia in modo impreciso (cosa non grave). Se leggi bene la domanda completa troverai quello che era inteso: "Is there any rule when to use an article?". Come scrivevo ieri, non esiste un motivo per certi fenomeni. Questo è conosciuto come principio di arbitrarietà di Saussure.

@greg "Il sito Meta non è per discutere delle particolari domande e risposte sul sito principale, ma per questioni generali sul sito" Il mio post aveva forse a che fare con domande e risposte sul sito generale? Qui abbiamo gravi problemi di comprensione! La mia domanda riguardava meccanismi di interazione. L' ho poi suffragata con un esempio concreto!

Nico, mi pare che tu ti stia scaldando troppo; certo questa 'comunità'
non aiuta, e allora provo a spiegare quello che ho capito io, e dove
mi portano le mie conclusioni.
Questo sito, o meglio comunità, si è formato ed evoluto fino a essere ciò che
è adesso, e continua a esserlo, grazie a diversi meccanismi. Uno dei meccanismi
lo si potrebbe definire istinto di auto conservazione, che tende a conservare
le cose così come sono. Come un popolo è orgoglioso della propria storia e della
propria cultura, così una comunità, anche se virtuale, tende a mantenersi
stabile con le proprie idee, ed è comprensibile che, quando in quella comunità
entrano elementi estranei con idee estranee, rimangano tutti spiazzati, anche in buona fede.
Ora che ho esplorato il sito mi sono fatto alcune idee; sono personali, mie, ma
forse qualcuna concide con la tua. Detto senza mezzi termini, questo sito è
il giocattolo di Charo, la sua casa delle bambole: usa il pettine per
raddrizzare gli accenti storti, per allineare i titoli delle domande,
aggiunge nuovi elementi alla collezione, e la casa delle bambole la appaga
con upvote su domande, risposte e commenti. Quando il meccanismo s'incrina
appena, ci rimane molto male, non le sembra vero che qualcuno possa non
essere in sintonia con il suo modo di vedere le cose. E' il suo punto di
vista, confortato ormai da anni di vita in questa comunità.
Si sente perfettamente a suo agio a citare
Dante a sproposito, probabilmente senza capirlo: mi chiedo infatti come possa
capire Dante una persona che non capisce il "significato di cavo a motore in questo contesto".
Talvolta non capisce neppure quello che scriviamo io e te.
Ma va bene così, io stesso ho detto che Charo mi stava simpatica, e mi sono
spinto perfino a suggerirle di scegliere altri autori (con grande stupore ho
scoperto che recentemente un autorevole membro di questo sito ha reiterato
lo stesso suggerimento). Per un poco sono anche stato al suo gioco; poi mi sono
reso conto che il gioco non m'interessa: io non voglio aiutare Charo a trovare
le sue risposte, voglio aiutare una platea più ampia, se posso, e quindi fare
delle ricerche su una parola come "arcuofolo", mi sembra vano - e mi sembra
pure vano, ormai, cercare di convincerla che una parola scritta in un libro
può non essere catalogabile con regionalismo, dialettalismo, termine colto e
via dicendo. Le parole sono mattoni che possono essere fabbricati male, anche
dal più colto scrittore; e con i mattoni non si fanno solo bei palazzi e chiese
e monumenti, si fanno anche stalle e latrine. I termini, e il loro significato ultimo, vengono scelti da chi
li impiega, non da chi li legge o da chi li cataloga.
In questo contesto poi s'inseriscono tutti i membri della comunità, ognuno con
la sua personalità. Hanno tutti ragione dal loro punto di vista. Ha ragione
Dag a inalberarsi se gli si dice "andiamoci piano": però a quel punto si sente
autorizzato a insultare con frasi come "hai le idee confuse", "dev'essere un
triste mondo il tuo", "stai salendo in cattedra", "trolla pure" e simili.
Ha ragione, perché lui in cattedra c'è già, talmente in alto che non s'accorge
che a buona parte degli italiani il verso degli accenti non interessa, e che
un'altra buona parte di italiani ama mettere l'iniziale maiuscola a tutte le
parole di un titolo o perfino di frasi che titoli non sono. A questo proposito
ho scritto un commento che diceva in modo generale "mi pare incredibile che
alcuni non si accorgano di questo fenomeno". E' intervenuta Charo puntualizzando
"ci siamo accorti, lo chiamiamo maiuscolite". Lei non c'entrava niente, è intervenuta per spirito di comunità. E' così che ci si aiuta in una comunità, s'interviene anche quando non si è chiamati in causa. Se qualcuno scrive cose diverse da quelle "normali", per esprimere un'opinione, per mostrare un punto di vista diverso, si scatena
la comunità. 
Il resto sono incomprensioni, crescendi di tono, insulti, e alla fine si
perde di vista l'obiettivo principale. Hanno poco da fare i moderatori, hanno
ragione anche loro, non è che, pur ammesso che vogliano, possano criticare chi critica. Allora cancellano commenti e risposte. Qualcuno, giustamente,
invita a postare risposte invece di commenti; magari dice a me che potrei
scrivere una risposta, e quando rispondo che non mi sento a mio agio mi
suggerisce che me la prendo troppo. Lui stesso però, sotto una mia risposta,
mi fa le pulci - sbagliando tra l'altro per non aver visto bene. Non è che mi
abbia aiutato, ma dal suo punto di vista ha aiutato il sito.
Quindi Nico, per concludere, hanno ragione loro. E' una vera comunità, con le sue
tradizioni, formata da membri che si vogliono bene e si aiutano l'un l'altro. E'
sbagliato incaponirsi, ognuno sta facendo ciò che dal suo punto di vista è giusto,
non ci sono errori, le statistiche invisibili agli utenti normali lo dimostrano.
Il sito è quello che è, ottiene esattamente quello che vuole. Siamo noi gli estranei,
forse siamo più adatti a un forum dove c'è più tolleranza e voglia di discutere,
questa è una comunità dove le idee personali, o magari solo le idee, non sono
ben accette: c'è già scritto tutto nei libri di grammatica, nei dizionari e nelle
parole scritte da autori presenti e passati.

I don't understand how you can say that this website is Charo's playground. Really, I think both you and Nico have a misunderstanding of the culture here. (Incidentally, for the time I misunderstood your post I deleted the criticism and apologized. I considered the question closed and I am sorry for the misreading, but I don't understand why you bring it up again)

@DenisNardin grazie, sei una persona gentile; il post al quale mi riferivo è il seguente: https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/11660/6017

@user070221 because we like to contribute; and I think that things will be better by the time passing. I understand your advice, anyway, you could be true. But I am not angry at all... I am just explaining what I think.

@DenisNardin: I'm replying to your comment stating "It is unclear what you'd like the moderators to do": don't know why, the site says me it is recent/unread. Well: I don't ask anything to moderators (also written in my answer above). I simply pointed out that answers with many downvotes and/or many critic comments are as awful, if not worse, than no answers at all. But: downvotes and about half of the comments are not made by the original answerer...

It could be better for the site, sometimes, to leave bad answers alone (or, better, accompanied by a good one). That's all; and I addressed you just because you're the one that sometimes writes "can someone write an answer". It is/were not a critique to you or any other moderator, instead a thought directed to all the users here.
